# Toggle menu-to-arrow icon on Toolbar

Tags: android, android-animation, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I need control the toggle of menu icon of Toolbar and transform to a arrow with animation. Not only when the user click and open or drag the drawer layout.

[image: animation to this]

I'm using the app compat v21.0

Comment: some useful examples https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui , https://github.com/balysv/material-menu

Comment: It can't be possible with Toolbar from appCompat?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following in styles

```
<resources>
    <style name="NavDrawer" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NavDrawerActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/teal</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/menu</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/back</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I need do it with animation.